# Regarding installing git source code via checkinstall

Tags: git, makefile, checkinstall

I'm running the OS Ubuntu 14.04 and I am going to install git via checkinstall.
Here is the step as per the git docs:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext \
    libz-dev libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install asciidoc xmlto docbook2x
tar -zxf git
cd git
make configure
./configure --prefix=/usr
make all doc info

sudo checkinstall install-doc install-html install-info
```

Run `checkinstall` insead of `make install` on above command and here is the output:

```
Installing with install-doc install-html install-info...

========================= Installation results ===========================
/var/tmp/tmp.5uGKarW0hS/installscript.sh: 4: /var/tmp/tmp.5uGKarW0hS/installscript.sh: install-doc: not found

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
```

Please help me out and thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to install git from source with checkinstall?

Comment: @EtanReisner It is easy to manage the package, such as remove.

Comment: I more meant why are you trying to install from source at all? Newer versions of git are packaged for newer versions of ubuntu it would probably be easier/better to try to rebuild a package from one of those versions.

Comment: @EtanReisner This version of Ubuntu is LTS(long-term support) and it is recommanded by its [official website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). And what more, I wanna learn how checkinstall to handle the install-doc problem since sometimes we have to install the latest version of the software from the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command `sudo checkinstall make install install-doc install-html install-info` and things get fixed.